# Entitiy Framework Core - First Migration With Existing Database

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

I started a project with an existing database and want to use the `code first` approach to do future changes.

First, I imported the existing entities using `the scaffold method`.

Now I'd like to change to the code first approach and initialize `the migrations`.

But when I perform an initial migration all the existing tables are added to the migration. How can I exclude the existing tables from migration resp. start with migrations at the status quo?

In ef it should be possible to use `-IgnoreChanges` but it seems not to work in `ef core` (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11134)). Is there a better workaround than to comment out the up method of the migration?

Thank you very much

Comment: The [recommended](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database#updating-the-model) [workaround](https://fildev.net/2018/03/30/ef-core-code-first-with-existing-database-asp-net-core/) is to comment out or delete the code in the 'Up' method of the migration file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my question was if there is another way than to comment out the migration.

Comment: OK, then not at the moment.  It looks like it might be on the list: [Improve existing database support](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2167) as part of:  [Improve experience for managing migrations](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22945), but  in backlog, not proposed